# How to SetFocus on a TextBox in the Form Load

Tags: ms-access, textbox, setfocus

Working in both A2003 & A2007.

How do we ensure that a selected TextBox gets the focus when the form loads? If we put MyTextBox.SetFocus in the Form_Load then we get the error:

```
can't move the focus to the control
```

This form is designed for rapid data entry, and the form somewhat rearranges itself based on the last used settings. So there are several different textboxes any of which may need the focus depending on the user. We can't just fix it in design time by giving MyTextBox TabIndex=0.

The help says something about calling Repaint which just doesn't make any sense at all:

> You can move the focus only to a
>   visible control or form. A form and
>   controls on a form aren't visible
>   until the form's Load event has
>   finished. Therefore, if you use the
>   SetFocus method in a form's Load event
>   to move the focus to that form, you
>   must use the Repaint method before the
>   SetFocus method.

Comment: Are you using `MyTextBox.SetFocus` (with the appropriate control name), or `Me!MyTextBox.SetFocus` (or `Me.MyTextBox.SetFocus`)? It's NEVER a good idea to refer to controls except as members of the parent form, and possibly there's a timing issue with setting up the namespace that is required to resolve an unspecified control reference. However, I just tried the unspecified control in my test form, and it worked just fine without Me! or Me.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton now i'm really confused. i thought kevin ross had clued me in

Comment: Kevin's answer doesn't really address the question. I didn't need Repaint in my test example at all. Did you clarify if you you had a recordsource and were sometimes opening the form with no records loaded? In that case, the controls won't exist so you can't set focus to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant set the focus as the controls don’t really exist yet, try putting the code in the OnActivate event instead

Or just put a DoCmd.Repaint in the OnLoad event before trying to set the focus. Both should work but I'm not near a computer to check

Comment: thanks for the answer. moving the code to OnActivate didn't work because the form is a popup and (apparently) there's no Activate event in Access for popups. But moving the code to the "Open" event (which i figure is pretty much the same thing) solved the problem.

Comment: when i googled why Form_Activate wasn't firing one of the results explained that there's no Form_Activate for popups, use Open instead, so I did. And it seems to work. Now you've got me worried though.

Answer (score 2):

The best bet in this case, is to ensure that the textbox to get focus is numbered 0 in the Tab Index property.

Comment: tag index or tab index? by the way congrats on becoming the first and so far only Gold badge member for tag [ms-access]

Comment: Congratulations.  I didn't notice you're golden.  :-)

Comment: @HansUp It is just very brightly polished brass, but in the right light ... :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've always gotten that error when the control I was trying to set focus to was either 1)**not visible** or 2)**not enabled**.  I assume you've already checked those, but it would be worth double checking at runtime when you get the error message (especially since you said you are shuffling the controls at runtime).

I use the .SetFocus method pretty regularly without trouble.  I don't recall ever getting an error message when setting focus to a control that already has it as Remou stated in his answer.

I believe there is also a third case that occurs if you try to set focus to a control in the *form header/footer* of a *bound* form that has had *all of its records filtered out*.  I know that situation causes "disappearing" contents in an unbound combo box, but I think it may also play havoc with the SetFocus method.  If you are opening the form in Data Entry mode, though, that should not be an issue.

Comment: i'm not asking why i'm getting the error. i understand that access doesn't allow us to setfocus in the form load because the form isn't yet visible. i'm asking how to dynamically specify which textbox WILL get the focus, given that you cannot do a SetFocus in the form load.

Comment: i see now.  sorry for the noise.

Comment: This post isn't noise at all. A visible form, even with PopUp set to True has no trouble setting focus to a visible and enabled control in the OnLoad event. I just tested. It has no problems. It even works if you open the popup form hidden. There's clearly something else going on here, just as you, @mwolfe02, alluded to, as the simple case works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Move SetFocus to the form's On Current event.  Should work then unless perhaps the form's record source contains no records and you've set the form's Allow Additions property to No.  In that case your text box will not be available to SetFocus on, but in my testing it doesn't throw an error.